# Seaborn countplot with second axis with ordered data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to create a countplot with a lineplot over it as practice for some data visualisation I will be doing in work. I am looking at the kickstarter data on kaggle [Link here](https://www.kaggle.com/kemical/kickstarter-projects)

I run a countplot with a hue on the state of the project (successful, failed, canceled) and both of these are ordered

```
filter_list = ['failed', 'successful', 'canceled']
df2 = df[df.state.isin(filter_list)]

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches( 16, 10)
sns.countplot(x='main_category', hue='state', data=df2, order = df2['main_category'].value_counts().index, 
              hue_order = df2['state'].value_counts().index)
```

This comes out as follows:
[image]

I then create my second axis and add a lineplot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches( 16, 10)

ax = sns.countplot(x='main_category', hue='state', data=df, ax=ax, order = df2['main_category'].value_counts().index, 
              hue_order = df2['state'].value_counts().index)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='main_category', y='backers', data=df2, ax =ax2)
```

But this changes the column labels as seen below:
[image]

It appears that the data is the same its just the order of columns is different. I am still learning so my code may be inefficent or some of it redundant but any help would be appreciated. The only other things are how df is created which is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('ks.csv')
df = df.drop(['ID'], axis = 1)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `lineplot` is what you are looking for. `lineplot` is supposed to be used [with numeric data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot), not categorical. I'm even surprised this worked at all.

I think you are looking for [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) instead

```
filter_list = ['failed', 'successful', 'canceled']
df2 = df[df.state.isin(filter_list)]
order = df2['main_category'].value_counts().index

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = sns.countplot(x='main_category', hue='state', data=df2, order=order, 
              hue_order=filter_list)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.pointplot(x='main_category', y='backers', data=df2, ax=ax2, order=order)
```

[image]

Note that used like that, `pointplot` will show the average number of backers across categories. If that's not what you want, you can pass another aggregation function using the `estimator=` paramater

eg

```
sns.pointplot(x='main_category', y='backers', data=df2, ax=ax2, order=order, estimator=np.sum)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is helpful, I am still learning these visualisations so it is good to pinpoint where I was going wrong